# How can I mimic this layout

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to mimic this layout using HTML/CSS. Attached is what it should look like on Desktop and Mobile. For mobile, I'm not 100% sure the best approach for this. Notice how the image comes before "Bowers & Wilkins".

The layout is 100% browser width btw. My initial thought was to use flex boxes for this...but I'm not 100% sure if it's the right approach. I'm currently pretty new to using flex boxes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can view the html and css in your browser to see exactly how they do this.

Comment: In this case this was an image sent to me created in Photoshop.

Comment: you want to look into responsive design.  Start with making it right on your smallest screen first.  It looks to me you should consider a container, and then within the container three sections or divs. one for exclusive orders, one for the img and one for the text.  Then use media queries to flip the layout around in css.  if you just want to use images you could do this with just one and change the img in css for the different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would probably be to float the image to the right at desktop res (initially shown in a single column in the demo when you run the below snippet - effectively mobile res. If you switch to full page mode, you should see the element order change so the image floats to the right):

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

/* float image to the right, half the width of the viewport */
img {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1em;
    width: 50vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* at mobile res, remove the float so the image appears back between the headings */
  img {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: .75em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" />

<h1>Exclusive offers from our partners</h1>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-200-200-4.jpg" />
<h2>Bowers &amp; Wilkins</h2>
<p>It's one thing to dress well for your party. It's another thing to host it well ...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend bootstrap as a good solution for this.  They have pre-built CSS classes that can pull and push and rearrange objects like this automatically.

Here the classes would be class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6" and class= "col-md-6 col-md-pull-6"